# T-SQL: [column] not like [any value from another select]

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have table `shop` with an `Email` column.

Also I have another table `Unsubscribed` with a `EmailPattern` column.

How I can select only shops with `Email` column does not match any `EmailPattern` value from `Unsubscribed` table?

Example:

Unsubscribed has these records:

```
aaa
bbb
ccc
```

I expect result like:

```
select * 
from Shop 
where Email not like "%aaa%" 
  and Email not like "%bbb%" 
  and Email not like "%ccc%"
```

Answer (score 5):

```
Select *
From shop
Where not exists (
  Select 1
  From unsubscribed
  Where shop.email like '%' + unsubcribed.emailpattern + '%'
)
```

Answer (score 0):

This will work:

```
-- setup test tables
CREATE TABLE #Shop (ID INT, Email VARCHAR(100));
CREATE TABLE #Unsubscribed (EmailPattern VARCHAR(100));

-- fill with example data
INSERT #Shop VALUES (1,'test@a.com');
INSERT #Shop VALUES (2,'david@r.com');
INSERT #Shop VALUES (3,'user@r.com');
INSERT #Shop VALUES (4,'george@usa.com');
 -- general phrase
INSERT #Unsubscribed VALUES ('test');
 -- specific email
INSERT #Unsubscribed VALUES ('user@r.com');
--INSERT #Unsubscribed VALUES ('@'); -- watch out, this will match every email!
--INSERT #Unsubscribed VALUES ('_'); -- so will this

-- filter results:
-- This returns rows from Table A (Shop), when they do not match anything in table B (Unsubscribed)
SELECT
    A.*
FROM
    #Shop A
    LEFT JOIN #Unsubscribed B ON A.Email LIKE '%' + B.EmailPattern + '%'
WHERE
    B.EmailPattern IS NULL;

DROP TABLE #Shop;
DROP TABLE #Unsubscribed;
```

Be aware that if certain phrases or characters get into the unsubscribe pattern, It can potentially match every record!

Comment: Please back up your assertion that it is more efficient. The query you posted uses a Left Join operator with a Filter; the WHERE NOT EXISTS directly uses a Left Anti Semi Join. As you add more rows to #Shop, the (slight) performance difference in favor of the latter increases.  Tested on MS-SQL 2008 and 2012.

Comment: See also: http://www.sqlperformance.com/2012/12/t-sql-queries/left-anti-semi-join

Comment: Good reading in this article, thanks for the link. I was not aware of this approach. My assertion has been removed.

Comment: In my spare time I will test this out using this particular example but with large datasets.

Comment: You can use an identity column in #Shop instead of specifying the ids manually.  Then you can just do `INSERT INTO #Shop (Email) SELECT Email FROM #Shop` a bunch of times to get a large dataset (the results are not particularly important)